# How to make QWidget get input method focus on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt5, qwidget, input-method-kit

I am using `QWidget` to create a mirrored window of my mobile phones on MacOS.

I'm using `setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled, true);` so that my `Qwidget` can get the text input from Sogou input method on Mac.

There is only one `QOpenGLWidget` in my `QWidget` to display mobile phone mirroring. When I click on some position of `Qwidget` and type , the display position of the Sogou input method is always under `Qwidget`, far away from where I clicked, because there is no input focus on `QOpenGLWidget`.

How can I do that?